# My ocelot won't tame!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried everything and I gave it 256 (yes 256) fish and it still won't tame! It's just running around in my house. If anyone can help me please do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tame ocelots any more.  You need a cat spawn egg or find them in villages.